# Telerik MVC Grid Edit All (or start in edit mode) ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a Telerik Grid in my ASP.net MVC application, and I want to bind some columns in edit mode - display textboxes, not the content.  Something like this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Reports)
    .Name("Reports")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.ID))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.ReportName).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(o => o.BeginDate).Format("{0:d}").Title("Begin Date");
        columns.Bound(o => o.EndDate).Format("{0:d}").Title("End Date");
        columns.Bound(o => o.DueDate).Format("{0:d}").Title("Due Date");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Comment);
    })
)
```

But without doing custom templates for the columns I want to edit (Dates and Comment).  Is this possible, or do I need to define a Template and ClientTemplate for each one I want to be able to edit?

Telerik gives some examples:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax

But I want a whole grid of textboxes, and I'll save them all at once.